# Why did my van hesitate, then stall and not restart?

Tags: fuel-system, stall, fuel-injection, econoline

I have a 1989 Econoline 250 with low miles (60k) was driving on the highway today when I suddenly lost power, tried to give it gas but it hesitated, then stalled so I pulled off. Check engine light was on I think (can't tell it always come on when I first try to restart). When I tried to restart, it cranked (strong) but just would not catch. Oil is full, battery showing full voltage, absolutely no problems before this. I got it towed, but I racking my brain to figure out what could have gone wrong. Any ideas ?

BTW the engine is fuel injected.

Comment: Lots of things, but most likely a fuel pressure/volume issue.  Out of gas, clogged fuel filter, or failing pump.

Comment: I'd second the clogged fuel filter.

Comment: '89 Ford probably about ready for a new fuel pump.

Comment: @SteveRacer that's an answer and a half right there :)

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Or maybe two, 'cuz it's owed.  (I'm a Ford guy and my therapy group says admission is the first part of recovery...)

Comment: @SteveRacer might want to add fuel pump relay to that list

Comment: @Zaid Or even a fuse.  But your brain says "yes" and my heart ('89 Ford) says "no".  But when we are alone at night contemplating our insignificance in this universe, the glowing letters on the walls of tenement halls says "fuel"...

Comment: Key question:  Let it sit.  Will it restart?  Might be just a fuel filter. @dlu

Comment: It would not restart ..... , felt like something just went, it was running really well and then this happened all the sudden, I suppose a clog can happen all the sudden, but it felt like something just went